# Javascript Android - rread file from sdcard internal storage

Tags: javascript, android

Is it possible to read a file found internal storage of android table by using javascript. I know it can be done by java because I tried it and worked?

The reason why I am doing this because the user for now will create an event and save it to an xml file and the I need to load it and display information on a calendar using DHX scheduler.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can read from external storage in a webview if you point the baseUrl to the file system with file://path_to_folder.

```
String localPath = "file://" + kmlmo.path;  // full path to some folder in file system.
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(localPath, myHtml, "text/html","UTF-8", "");
```

Watch out now the relative urls in your html and javascript will also point to the file system so anything you have to get from the web has to have the complete http path.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/fish.jpg" />
```

where on the interweb you would code the image as

```
<img src="images/fish.jpg" />
```

Comment: I don't know if this works for internal storage like you asked.